# Simple Prefix Matching Library in Haskell

Tags: haskell

For some context, I'm trying to write a streaming tokenizer in Haskell and noticed that I was writing a lot of functions with the type signature `String -> Maybe Int` that attempted to consume "the longest possible token matching a particular pattern" from the input stream. The pattern might be something like a quoted string literal in JSON.

I tried using Parsec for a while to get a "prefix matcher", but I kept getting tripped up over what the appropriate userstate is supposed, and what the `m` argument in `ParsecT` means. Parsec is probably a strict superset of the functionality that this little library exposes.

A "Matcher" is anything with the type `String -> Maybe Int`. Matchers are supposed to be greedy and produce the longest prefix that they possibly can. There's also an unenforced property that, in cases where the match is a proper prefix of the input string, adding more characters to the end of a string doesn't extend the prefix. The library also encourages / permits users to write sloppy grammars (for instance using `symOrExn`) that fail in ugly ways.

I could use some helping figuring out how to generalize `String -> Maybe Int`. I don't know what class I should insist on for the input `Eq a => [a]` is the first thing that comes to mind, but it might be possible to make something more general than that. As for the output type maybe a type that's constrained to be a monoid or a group? I really just need a notion of zero and the ability to increment for the index. ... although it might also be possible to generalize the notion of a "prefix" to tree-like structures.

I'm hoping to structure this library eventually as a collection of really concrete implementations for a handful of commonly-used text-like types, as well as a generic implementation that can be used in other circumstances. Advice on how to generalize the library is much appreciated.

```
module Text.PrefixMatcher.String where
import Data.List

-- A simple non-generic prefix matching library
-- with a few simple combinators
--
-- a Matcher has type (String -> Maybe Int)
--
-- It takes a String and returns a number corresponding
-- to the length of the matched prefix.
--
-- The intended use case here is to provide a simple utility
-- to help in converting a string to a stream of tokens.
--
-- makeMatcher -- make a matcher for a constant string
-- 

type Matcher = String -> Maybe Int


identityMatcher :: Matcher
identityMatcher str = Just 0


makeMatcher :: String -> Matcher
makeMatcher spec str = case isPrefixOf spec str of
    True -> Just (length spec)
    False -> Nothing


andThen :: Matcher -> Matcher -> Matcher
andThen m1 m2 str = ltotal where
    l1 = m1 str
    ltotal = case l1 of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        (Just l1) ->
            let rest = drop l1 str in
            let l2 = m2 str in
            case l2 of
                Nothing -> Nothing
                (Just l2) -> Just (l1 + l2)


symOrExn :: Matcher -> Matcher -> Matcher
symOrExn m1 m2 str = res where
    l1 = m1 str
    l2 = m2 str
    res = case (l1, l2) of
        -- good cases
        (Just l1, Nothing) -> Just l1
        (Nothing, Just l2) -> Just l2
        -- bad cases
        (Nothing, Nothing) -> Nothing
        -- if you reach this case, the grammar was
        -- constructed badly
        (Just l1, Just l2) -> error "ambiguous match"


leftOr :: Matcher -> Matcher -> Matcher
leftOr m1 m2 str = result where
    l1 = m1 str
    l2 = m2 str

    result = case (l1, l2) of
        (Just l1, _) -> Just l1
        (Nothing, Just l2) -> Just l2
        (Nothing, Nothing) -> Nothing


andThenList :: [Matcher] -> Matcher
andThenList [] = identityMatcher
andThenList [x] = x
andThenList (x:xs) = andThen x (andThenList xs)


leftOrList :: [Matcher] -> Matcher
leftOrList [] = identityMatcher
leftOrList [x] = x
leftOrList (x:xs) = leftOr x (leftOrList xs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're on the right track, and this might eventually evolve into a parser, or converge to an existing one.

From software engineering point of view, I'd suggest to make `Matcher` a `newtype`. This better separates its API from the implementation, and allows to do changes later without breaking the API.

Notice these two functions:

```
identityMatcher :: Matcher
andThen :: Matcher -> Matcher -> Matcher
```

This looks very much like a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) (see also [Monoid](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monoid) on Haskell Wiki). And this is what you indeed want from your parser - to be compositional, and to adhere to certain laws: associativity and identity. So it'd make sense to have a [`Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Monoid) instance for `Matcher`. Note that then `andThenList` becomes just [mconcat](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:mconcat).

Another `Monoid` instance would be `leftOr`, whose identity would be a matcher that's always failing `const Nothing`. This is very much like there are two monoids for natural numbers - multiplication with 1 (`andThen`) and addition with 0 (`leftOr`). We'll back to this later.

The next thing you might consider is to return a value from your matcher. For constant matchers this isn't that useful, but there are multiple reasons why this can be useful:

- The matchers can optionally parse the input, for example when matching numbers, they can already return the parsed number.
- Some matchers might match multiple strings, and then it's useful to be able to provide more information about the outcome (for example, regex matched groups).
- A simple example of the previous point is when calling `leftOr`, you might want to know which of the matchers matched. Returning a value allows you to distinguish that.
- Sometimes it's useful if a matcher can depend on the result of the previous match.
- When you don't need a value, it's easy to disregard/discard it, by using  `()` as the result.

This leads you to creating a [monadic](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad) interface of your parser. So your type could be something like:

```
newtype Matcher a = Matcher (String -> Maybe (a, Int))`.
```

Interestingly, the inner type is already a monad, corresponding to `ReaderT String (WriterT (Sum Int) Maybe a)`, or alternatively `RWST String (Sum Int) () Maybe a`. Now standard monadic [`>>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62-) should correspond to `andThen` and [`return`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) to the identity matcher. And also [`mplus`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mplus) to `leftOr`. Such an interface will give your matchers all the power monads offer with very little effort.

---

Regarding your paragraph

> I tried using Parsec for a while to get a "prefix matcher", but I kept getting tripped up over what the appropriate userstate is supposed, and what the m argument in ParsecT means. Parsec is probably a strict superset of the functionality that this little library exposes.

If you don't need any user state, you can just ignore it. And the `m` argument allows you to run your parser in another monad - `ParsecT` is a [monad transformer](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers). If you don't need it, just use `Identity`, which is exactly how [`Parsec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#t:Parsec) is defined.

You might be interested in using [`ReadP`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html), a conceptually simpler parser bundled with GHC.

Also [this blog post](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/002_parsers.html) about writing your own, simple parser, might be useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Library functions, particularly Maybe's Applicative/Alternative instances, can make your code more consise:

```
makeMatcher spec str = length spec <$ guard (isPrefixOf spec str)

andThen m1 m2 str = do
  l1 <- m1 str
  l2 <- m2 $ drop l1 str
  Just $ l1 + l2

symOrExn m1 m2 str = case catMaybes [m1 str, m2 str] of
  [] -> Nothing
  [l] -> Just l
  -- if you reach this case, the grammar was
  -- constructed badly
  [_, _] -> error "ambiguous match"

leftOr = liftA2 (<|>)

andThenList = foldr andThen identityMatcher

leftOrList = foldr leftOr identityMatcher
```

A more potent approach is to return not the length at which to split, but the results of the split. In fact, `StateT String Maybe String` makes this work out of the box:

```
type Matcher = StateT String Maybe String

makeMatcher :: String -> Matcher
makeMatcher spec = StateT $ fmap (spec,) . stripPrefix spec

runMatcher :: Matcher -> String -> Maybe (String, String)
runMatcher = runStateT

andThen = liftA2 (++)

symOrExn m1 m2 = m1 <* (m2 *> error "ambiguous match" <|> pure ()) <|> m2
  -- I'll admit, this one looks clunky

leftOr = (<|>)

andThenList = fmap concat . sequenceA

leftOrList = asum
```